# How to use Metal to draw ARMeshAnchor?

Tags: ios, swift, metal, realitykit, metalkit

I use MTKView and ARSession, and set:

```
configuration.sceneReconstruction = .mesh   
session.run(configuration)
```

Through

```
let meshAnchors = frame!.anchors.compactMap { $0 as? ARMeshAnchor }
```

I can get all ARMeshAnchor.

How to render these meshes into Metal, don’t need to care about the texture.